# How to install javax.microedition.lcdui in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, import

Whenever I try to use this code...

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
```

...it shows this error "javax.microedition.lcdui does not exist"

How do I resolve this issue?

It is installed...

"http://gyazo.com/ccd667e24ea2952112cd9fdcd064e0c2"

Comment: Is the relevant library on the classpath or build path of the Netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the JME library/JARs to your project's classpath. You can do this by right clicking on the project and selecting Properties from the popup menu.